# How to express "until ~" in Chinese?

Tags: mandarin, conjunction

Suppose that I want to express the following (sample) sentence:

> There is still 3 hours until the departure of the flight.

If you use a dictionary, the matched entries for "until" would be something like the follows:

> 到飞机起飞还有三个小时。

However, I feel it is a bit awkward, and also feel that 到 is not the appropriate word here, at least I don't think Chinese people use it much often.

Another example:

> X: 下次等到假期准备在那多玩几天
>
> I: Then until you come here I should improve my speaking skills!

With my limited writing skills, I might write it like:

> 那到你下次来的时，我应该学多。

In these cases, is 到 the appropriate word or how should I express "until ~" better in Chinese?

Comment: until 到…时候 e。g。到飞机起飞的时候

Comment: @user6065 Is it OK that simple? Then the next example should be OK as well? (It is 时, not 时候 but I think it is the same)

Comment: It's hard to say which one is *appropriate* because they're all correct. IMO "离飞机起飞" or "距离飞机起飞", and "在你下次来之前" sound more natural.

Comment: find examples for  到。。。时 at iciba:到第三圈时，金基德的车速达到了每小时289英里(by the 3rd lap), 比赛进行到第30分钟时双方都更换了守门员, also 直到…时候(为止)

Comment: @songyuanyao The third example sounds quite natural for me. I wonder the use of 到 sounds a bit awkward, even though it might be grammatically correct, so posted a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, you cannot expect to translate Chinese to English (or English to Chinese) literally, word-by-word. The way that a sentence is constructed is way too different in these languages that translate word-by-word would lead to all kinds of awkward situations.

In your first example,

> There is still 3 hours until the departure of the flight.

I would consider the following expressions in spoken language:

```
   飞机              还有  3个小时               起飞。
The flight | (is) | still 3 hours | (from) | departure.
```

To emphasize 3 hours:

```
   飞机       还有  3个小时        才         起飞。
the flight | still 3 hours | only until | take off.
 还有  3个小时      飞机           才         起飞。
still 3 hours | the flight | only until | take off.
==> The plane will only take off until 3 hours later.
```

Note that "until" is left out or changed by reordering those elements in your original sentence.

Or if you want **to make it feel like an announcement** (more formal), change the word to 距离(also means "until" in some situation) will be more suitable:

```
 距离             飞机起飞                  还有         3个小时。
Until | the departure of the flight | there is still | 3 hours.
```

---

As for the second example, it also requires some reordering and changes to wording:

> Then until you come here I should improve my speaking skills!

```
 那           你下次来之前，        我  应该            多    练习。
Then | before you come next time | I should | (do) | more practice.
==> Then I should practice more before you come next time.
```

---

However, it doesn't mean that you have to left out "until" every time. Consider this example:

```
The company was in chaos until he became the manager.
```

Including "until" here or not makes the meaning quite different:

```
直到他成为经理之前，公司一片混乱。
　　他成为经理之前，公司一片混乱。
```

You can infer from the first sentence that *he* is the key to the change of company. But the latter sentence could simply be a statement of fact, not necessarily credit him for the change.

---

So, the expression for "until" depends very much on the context IMO.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the great answer. Then how should I use apart 到 and 直到? I feel that 直到 has stronger "until" nuance, but is this correct?

Comment: @Blaszard I don't have a dictionary at hand to give you the exact definition. But from my understanding: 直到means only until (certain things happened) or only until (a certain time), sometimes used together with 才. 百度百科 gives 直到 the following definition: 一直到(多指时间). And here are some examples I found: 1. 他工作了很久，直到半夜才休息。 2. 他一直往梯子上爬，直到喘不过气来。 In the first example, I think it is ok to change 直到 with 到. But in the second, it would only make sense with 到 if you change it to this: ……爬，(直)到喘不过气来才<停下 or whatever happened next>. I hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is an tricky question. In most cases, 到 would be the best. But it would be a bit different in your question "Then until you come here I should improve my speaking skills!" The better translation would be 你下次来之前，我应该多学习。 Studying would be a behavior during this period of time. This could be a bit confusing because 之前 might sounds like "before" if you use a dictionary. In Chinese, if we are talking about time, 到 would be a better choice just like 到飞机起飞还有三个小时. But when we are talking about a behavior or experience during a period of time. 之前 would be more appropriate. Just like "我听到那个消息之前还感觉很快乐"I felt very happy until i heard that message. Another example would be 我听到铃声之前在读书 i was reading until i heard the bell. Basically 到 would describe purely time.

Answer (score 0):

The 到 in first simple is appropriate to use.

This 到 in here has no difference with "arrive" actually, not "places arrive" but "timing arrive", 距離 is the same. Basically the only difference between 距離 and 到 is that the 到 in here is a verb and 距離 is more like a noun,  when we use 距離 , we already know the time mostly, but 到 we can also using for asking, like 到什麼時候 .

距離 in the first simple is focus on "3 hours" and 到 is focus on "the departure of the flight" , this sentence has all information they need , so it's ok to use both.

Next question,
Because "improve my speaking skills" should be done before "you come here", we need to add 之前 behind 你下次來 not 時 , And because there's no exactly timing in this sentence, we prefer use 到 more than 距離 .

Answer (score 0):

When does our plane take off?
我们的飞机什么时候飞起？
There are still 3 hours until the departure of the flight, don't worry.
离飞机起飞还有三个小时，别担心。